# Why testing for the sign of the int is called "sloppy code" in glibc reference?

Tags: c, glibc, getc

In [glibc reference](http://www.sbin.org/doc/glibc/libc_6.html) we find such words:

> ...sloppy code like
>
> ```
> {
>   int c;
>   ...
>   while ((c = getc (fp)) < 0)
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> has to be rewritten...

Why testing for the sign of the int is called "sloppy code" in glibc reference?

Comment: It's already explained just below (your quote) i.e. WEOF need not be nagative.

Comment: Just read text around that code more carefully. It is not about testing of sign. It is about comparing result with `WEOF / EOF` explicitly. `EOF` is required to be negative, and this is the only negative value that `getc()` may return.  So it is a popular bad habit to write `getc() < 0` instead of `getc() != EOF`. And this habit may be interpolated to `wgetc()`, but since `WEOF` need not to be negative,  code like `wgetc() < 0` may not work as expected.

Comment: @Sergio: this remark about `WEOF` and `EOF` is strictly correct, but it would be intentionally misleading to defined `WEOF` do something different from `EOF` and that either of these be different from `-1`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, It surely would be misleading. Nevertheless MSVC headers declare `wint_t` as `unsigned short`, and `WEOF` like `(wint_t)0xFFFF`.  That is definitely not a `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the use of `WEOF`  macro. As already mentioned in the [reference](http://www.sbin.org/doc/glibc/libc_6.html), (*emphasis mine*)

> `WEOF` need not be the same value as `EOF` and unlike `EOF` **it also need *not* be negative.** [...]

So, checking for `< 0` might be a wrong decision, strictly speaking, it should be checked against the return value of `WEOF` itself.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko it is not strictly about `WEOF`, this is a generic problem, the example used there is `WEOF`, is that's your concer regarding the _sloppy_ part.